How do I add filters to a custom post type?
I have a custom post type in WP and the posts are displaying on the page but my filters are not linked to the CPT. My filters are being pulled from 'Posts' and not the CPT?
There are a few custom categories under the resource CPT but the 'Posts' categories are displaying on the page instead?
Here's my code:
        <?php
            get_template_part('templates/regions/region', 'head');
            get_template_part('templates/regions/region', 'header');
        ?>

        <main id="content">
            <div class="fullcol hero-section hero-section__simple-heading with-border with-filters">
            <div class="breadcrumb">
                        <?php get_breadcrumb(); ?>
                        </div>
                <div class="midcol lead-heading clearfix">
                    <h3 class="key-heading">Resources</h3>
                    <ul class="filter-links align-right">
                        <li><a href="/resources/">All</a></li>
                        <?php wp_list_categories( array(
                            'post_type'=> 'resource',
                            'orderby'    => 'name',
                            'title_li'   => '',
                            'exclude'    => array(1)
                        ) ); ?> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="fullcol blog-section blog-section__archive-grid">
                <div class="midcol clearfix">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <div class="fullcol archive-grid">
                        <?php 
                //$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                //$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
                //query_posts($args);

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'resource',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
                $recent = new WP_Query( $args );
                
                
                //$recent = new WP_Query ("post_type=resource&posts_per_page=9"); 
                    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            
                            //while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                            $thumburl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                            if($thumburl){
                                $thethumb = $thumburl;
                                $thumbclass = "has-thumbnail";
                            }else{
                                $thethumb = '';
                                $thumbclass = "no-thumbnail";
                            }
                        ?>
                            <div class="post-item anim-target bottomfade-fm-dm">
                                <div class="post-image bg-image rounded-box <?php echo $thumbclass; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thethumb; ?>);"></div>
                                <span class="post-date goblue"><?php the_time('d|m|Y'); ?></span>
                                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <div class="post-link">
                                    <a class="nexbtn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
            <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
                    <?php //wp_pagenavi(); ?>
            
                    <?php else:
                        echo "No posts found";
                    endif; 
                            wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

        <?php
            get_template_part('templates/regions/region', 'footer');
        ?>


wp_list_categories accepts taxonomy not post type - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/
